# Why only last line is printing while fetching in the dictionary also need to replace None with 0

Tags: python

Code is below

```
from decimal import Decimal
sample = [
    ("Book", Decimal("10.000"), Decimal("0E-20"), None),
    ("Pen", Decimal("66.66666"), Decimal("0E-20"), None),
    ("Pencil", Decimal("100.0000"), Decimal("0E-20"), 'G'),
]


data = {}
for i in sample:
    
    try:
        data['prod'] = i[0]
        data['test1'] = round(i[1])
        data['test2'] = round(i[2])
        data['test3'] = round(i[3])
      
    except:
        pass

print(data)
```

My Output is

```
{'prod': 'Pencil', 'test1': 100, 'test2': 0}
```

Expected out is all 3 dictionary

- if `None` then in dictionary it has to replace by 0

  ```
   {'prod': 'Book', 'test1': 10.00, 'test2': 0, 'test3':0}
    {'prod': 'Pen', 'test1': 66.66, 'test2': 0, 'test3':0}
    {'prod': 'Pencil', 'test1': 100, 'test2': 0, 'test3':'G'}
  ```

Expected out

`[{'prod': 'Book', 'test1': 10, 'test2': 0, 'test3': 0}, {'prod': 'Pen', 'test1': 67, 'test2': 0, 'test3': 0}, {'prod': 'Pencil', 'test1': 100, 'test2': 0, 'test3': 'G'}]`

Comment: you have one dictionary called `data`, why do you expect 3? you're looping 3 times, but overwriting the keys each tiem

Comment: `dictionaries` in python have distict `keys`. And you are setting values to the same `key` all the three times

Comment: If you just want to _print_ three dictionaries, move the `print()` to be the last line inside the `try` block.  Do you actually want to _create_ three separate ones instead?

Comment: If you only want to print, you can move the `print` inside `try` as @JohnGordon says. Tell me otherwise

Comment: @Chris_Rands is right, you have only one dictionary, but you want three? Maybe you want a *list* of dictionaries? In which case you should set data to be a list, create a new dictionary within the `for` loop, and then append the new dictionary to the list.

Comment: `try`/`except: pass` is the rankest of code smell. You're silencing every error short of segfaulting the interpreter; this is a great way to not understand why your code is breaking. If nothing else, make it `except (IndexError, ValueError):` to silence the specific errors you're expecting. And I'd suggest while debugging, output the error message so you understand when it's firing (`except (IndexError, ValueError) as e: print('Errored on', i, 'with message', e)`)

Comment: @ShadowRanger Well it seems the errors he wants to catch would be `TypeError`s, since doing `round()` on `None` or `str`s would raise such errors. As you noted though, OP should be very careful with silencing such errors.

Comment: @ChristianDean: Sure; somehow I had `float` in my mind (which would `ValueError` on `str`, but yeah `None` would still be `TypeError`). Point is, `except: pass` ensures you have no idea whether its an expected or unexpected error.

Comment: Right, of course. That's a practice that should be avoided @ShadowRanger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a list of dictionaries and add each dictionary to it:

```
from decimal import Decimal
sample = [
    ("Book", Decimal("10.000"), Decimal("0E-20"), None),
    ("Pen", Decimal("66.66666"), Decimal("0E-20"), None),
    ("Pencil", Decimal("100.0000"), Decimal("0E-20"), 'G'),
]


datalst=[]    # <-----

for i in sample:
    data = {} # <-----
    data['prod'] = i[0]
    data['test1'] = round(i[1])
    data['test2'] = round(i[2])
    data['test3'] = i[3] if i[3] else 0  # <---- if None add 0 else original value
    datalst.append(data)   #  <-----

print(datalst)
```

Comment: test3 is 0,0,'G' which is not coming, if None replaced by 0 and if not None the same things as it like G

Comment: Oops, wrong code in clipboard. Now it is working with `data = {}` within the loop.

Comment: now it will be 0 for test3 but not that is not the  case   `[{'prod': 'Book', 'test1': 10, 'test2': 0, 'test3': 0}, {'prod': 'Pen', 'test1': 67, 'test2': 0, 'test3': 0}, {'prod': 'Pencil', 'test1': 100, 'test2': 0, 'test3': 'G'}]`

Comment: Oh ok, thought you where testing whether round() works on i[3] or not. In that case you don't need a try-except clause at all. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting *3* dictionaries to be printed, but `data` only contains 1 (with the last values for each element assigned to it).

Comment: Scott, I say this with all respect, but wouldn't this be better as a comment on the post? I'm not going to downvote this because it is correct, but I'm not sure it really answers the OP's question?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do it this way:

```
from decimal import Decimal
from collections import defaultdict
sample = [
    ("Book", Decimal("10.000"), Decimal("0E-20"), None),
    ("Pen", Decimal("66.66666"), Decimal("0E-20"), None),
    ("Pencil", Decimal("100.0000"), Decimal("0E-20"), 'G'),
]
data = defaultdict(list)
for i in sample:
    try:
        data['prod'].append(i[0])
        data['test1'].append(round(i[1]))
        data['test2'].append(round(i[2]))
        data['test3'].append(round(i[3]))
    except:
        pass

print(dict(data))
```

That prints the following line to stdout:

```
{'prod': ['Book', 'Pen', 'Pencil'], 'test1': [10, 67, 100], 'test2': [0, 0, 0], 'test3': []}
```

UPDATE:
Given that you need a different output as per your comment BELOW, I changed the code above as follows:

```
from decimal import Decimal
sample = [
    ("Book", Decimal("10.000"), Decimal("0E-20"), None),
    ("Pen", Decimal("66.66666"), Decimal("0E-20"), None),
    ("Pencil", Decimal("100.0000"), Decimal("0E-20"), 'G'),
]
data = []
for i in sample:
    row = {}
    try:
        row['prod'] = i[0]
        row['test1'] = round(i[1])
        row['test2'] = round(i[2])
        row['test3'] = i[3] or 0
    except:
        pass
    finally:
        data.append(row)

print(data)
```

The output produced is:

```
[{'prod': 'Book', 'test1': 10, 'test2': 0, 'test3': 0}, {'prod': 'Pen', 'test1': 67, 'test2': 0, 'test3': 0}, {'prod': 'Pencil', 'test1': 100, 'test2': 0, 'test3': 'G'}]
```

Comment: test3 is 0,0,'G' which is not coming, if None replaced by 0 and if not None the same things as it like `G`

Comment: Expected out [{'prod': 'Book', 'test1': 10, 'test2': 0, 'test3': 0}, {'prod': 'Pen', 'test1': 67, 'test2': 0, 'test3': 0}, {'prod': 'Pencil', 'test1': 100, 'test2': 0, 'test3': 'G'}]